# routing in zendframework 2 is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

```
/* Here is my module config */



'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
    'User\Controller\User' => 'User\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

          'user' => array(
            'type' => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/user',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'User\Controller\User',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(

                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

And Controller as

class UserController extends AbstractActionController{

```
public function indexAction(){
    parent::indexAction();
    return new ViewModel();
}

public function addAction(){
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

}

whenever I try to access zf.localhost/user/user/add

It throws error as

Page not found.

The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
    user(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: user)

No Exception available

*I can't figure out why the routing is not working.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access controller named user which doesn't exists. You have two options:

1. Change `'route' => '/[:controller][/:action]'` to `'route' =>
   '/:action'`. And it will search for an action in your User\Controller\UserAction
2. Add to `controllers` new alias `'aliases' => array('user' => 'User\Controller\User')`