# The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class in ZF2

Tags: controller, routes, zend-framework2, action

First, I must say. I was looking for similar topics, but they did not working for me. (in this -> [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516680/routing-in-zendframework-2-is-not-working), this->[topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921558/zend-framework-2-skeleton-applications-example-not-working))

So get to the point. I try to call my simple controllew with simple model, like in tutorial. But i have typical error:

**The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.
Controller:
Blog(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Blog)**

Please explain to me what the problem?
For comfort demonstrate I prepared some images:

My Module_php 
[Module_php](http://savepic.net/6572968.htm)
My module_config_php
 [Module](http://savepic.net/6563756.htm)

*I can post only 2 links, so i push Controller code Here:*

```
namespace Wellnine\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class BlogController extends AbstractActionController
{
protected $blogTable;

public function showAllPostsAction()
{
    return new ViewModel(array(
        'posts' => $this->getBlogTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

public function getBlogTable()
{
    if (!$this->blogTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->blogTable = $sm->get('Wellnine\Model\BlogTable');
    }
    return $this->blogTable;
}
```

Comment: You could take a look at this : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html

Comment: Please try to change your route to remove the leading backslash from your 'namespace'.

If that not will help set _Wellnine\Controller\Blog_ as controller default and delete namespace arg

Comment: Many thanks for your help. It`s realy help me (I apologize for a rough mistakes)